# How can I understand what happens to my laptop?

Tags: graphics-card, kernel, ubuntu-14.04, nvidia-graphics-card, downgrade

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS which was recently upgraded to 14.04.03. With that upgrade came a new kernel (i.e. `3.11.0-18-generic`) that breaks my X server. If I select a previous kernel version (i.e. `3.11.0-17-generic`) on my GRUB recovery menu, I can boot my laptop with no problems at all, although the NVIDIA graphics card seems to lack a proper driver.

Surprisingly, if I boot with the new kernel in **recovery mode** everything works a treat (even the X server). I find myself reluctant to downgrade my kernel but unable to understand what might be causing the graphics card issue.

I tried updating the drivers, bumblebee and installing propietary drivers without success. How can I understand what's going on and solve this issue? I mean, there's obviously an issue with the graphics drivers, influenced somehow by the kernel version but I can't seem to understand what exactly.

Comment: Try to change to Nouveau (the opensource driver, present by default), and reboot. If it appears to work fine (except 3D acceleration), then it is related to the Nvidia proprietary BLOB. In that case just make sure to get the latest version of the proprietary driver. Please note: Don't try Nouveau if you have a series 900 GPU or a 750.

Comment: If you are using the proprietary nvidia driver, do you have the right kernel modul for your new kernel?

Comment: @ThomasWeinbrenner Note that according to him, it was a minor change. It probably was just a matter of packaging. I'm not into Ubuntu, but usually in the kernel the third digit is meant for bugfixes, and the forth for packaging. Probably redoing the nvidia kernel module would solve, but I have no idea on how to do it in Ubuntu, so uninstalling (going back to Nouveau) and install the blob again should solve.

Comment: I have a GT GeForce 750M so I won't try Nouveau as @CláudioPereira suggested. The propietary driver didn't work either but how can I be sure that I had the right kernel module? I suppose the installer script takes that into account, doesn't it?